# printing text into a file in Matlab

Tags: matlab, logging, text-files

I want to log the running of my program, specifically the running time of each part. At this moment I print to the screen using `disp`. Is there a way so that some of the things I print would also be printed into a text file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [DIARY](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/diary.html) command, that captures everything from the command window.

Answer (score 2):

There are other solutions to this problem where you write to one or more logfiles opened when your program is running. This provides a permanent record without polluting your work space or diary. It also works well if you compile your MATLAB application.

Jan Simon has a nice solution at [MATLAB Central](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/1905-logging-in-a-matlab-script) which uses a persistant file id so the log to file mechanism can be used again and again throughout an application with many functions without passing the file id about.

Others at MATLAB Central ([here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33532-log4matlab) and [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37701-log4m-a-powerful-and-simple-logger-for-matlab/content/log4m.m)) have developed class based solutions with more features.

Answer (score 1):

Also, [`fprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fprintf.html).